# VS2015 build error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sharepoint, dll, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to deploy GAC into the sharepoint. Deployment fails with this error message:

> Error occured in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: **Microsoft.Practices.Sharepoint.Common.dll**

The problem is that mentioned .dll inside `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common\v4.0_2.0.0.0__ef4330804b3c4129\` folder is somehow locked by another .dll called `Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll`.

Only one working solution is restarting windows server, but problem will happen again once I will try to deploy a newer version.

Is there any other solution how to prevent blocking this and other similar dlls?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to build the solution to generate a solution file, then use the powershell cmdlets `Add-SPSolution` or `Update-SPSolution` to add the solution to the farm? You should be able to use the `-GacDeployment` flag to have the solution automatically add the DLLs to the GAC.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. No, using powershell doesn't help to solve the issue.
In my opinion, VS 2015 blocks itself. Because restarting followed by clean | build | deploy helps to solve issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process named `Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll` supplies the feature "CodeLens" in the Visual Studio IDE. This feature supplies some nice functionality in VS like live display of references to functions above their declaration, source control status, test status and some others.

The problem will go away if you disable "CodeLens" in Visual Studio at

> Visual Studio Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Code Lens

[image: Visual Studio Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Code Lens]

If you don't want to disable CodeLens all the time on that computer, you can just kill `Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll` before deploying. This will temporarily disable CodeLens in all running instances of Visual Studio, but CodeLens will work again after restarting Visual Studio.

To automate killing the process before trying to register the assembly to the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), add the following command to the same place before your call to gacutil:

```
taskkill /f /im Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll
```

---

The actual trigger of the problem is that at least one of your projects in the solution loads the assembly `Microsoft.Practices.Sharepoint.Common.dll` from the GAC from within the Visual Studio IDE. You can prevent this by having the assembly reference point to a version of `Microsoft.Practices.Sharepoint.Common.dll` outside the GAC.

---

The issue was also [discussed at Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1656612/microsoft-alm-shared-remoting-remotecontainer-locks-dependent-project-output-files-solution-fails-recompilation). Microsoft does not see this a bug and says registering an assembly to the GAC and using assemblies from the GAC during build is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue "**Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: itextsharp.dll.**" I un-installed itextsharp.dll from the GAC and it resolved the issue.

Comment: While the structure of the error is the same, it clearly relates to a different assembly—and doesn’t likely explain the specific issue discussed here (which was already answered four years ago). Nor does it offer good general guidance for solving these types of issues since uninstalling a library often isn’t an option. That’s a bit like someone saying they’re having an error with an application and suggesting it can be fixed by not using the application.