# Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache:Select.Pdf.dll

Tags: sharepoint, gac

I add licensed select.pdf.dll to my SharePoint project. This dll file has added in both the visual studio reference and the package section(Deploy target as 'Global Assembly Cache (GAC)').

I was not able to deploy my solution to my sharepoint development server, with the error message

“Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: Select.Pdf.dll.”

I have googled the problem, someone cannot deploy because the .dll they want to deploy already existed in %windir%\assembly folder and the .dll is locked by other process. 
[VS2015 build error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336536/vs2015-build-error-cannot-add-the-specified-assembly-to-the-global-assembly-cac)
https://devramblings.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/error-cannot-add-the-specified-assembly-to-the-global-assembly-cache/

However, the "Select.Pdf.dll" I want to deploy has never been deployed before, the %windir%\assembly and %windir%\Microsoft.Net\assembly folders do not have same name dll. file in them.

I have tried to restart VS, and reset IIS. the problem still existed.

Is there any way to solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relevant .dep files also.  When you add your assembly to the advanced section of the package you can add Class Resources at the bottom of the dialog.  In my case I had to add Select.Tools.dep and Select.Html.dep before I could deploy my sharepoint solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Mundi's answer works, only clarification is that for us, only selecting Select.Html.dep was enough. It is to be noted that you have to specify that you want to view all files (not just .dll) when selecting the additional Class Resources.

Alternative solution that worked for development scenario (but not advisable for production) is using appropriate gacutil.exe to your .net version.